# How to execute a shell script using cronjob?

Tags: shell, unix, cron

I have created a shell script(Main) which encapsulates/calls several other shell scripts(child).
When the main shell script is ran manually it executes as expected, including the child shell scripts.

But when I execute the main shell script using cronjob, child shell scripts write logs as expected but on checking the results of child shell scripts, they don't return expected results.
Please help. Do let me know if you need more information?

Comment: Have a look at [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it), particularly the parts about debugging and about 'restricted environments.'

Comment: *nod*. To get more specific debugging advice, you need to ask a more specific question; right now, this is a general enough question that the general answers apply. BTW, the [`cron` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) is a helpful resource.